# How to write a QRegExp that will accept only strings made of characters or normal symbols?

Tags: regex, qt

Let me clarify the question. I need to process keyboard input on the fly. So if the user presses something like the home button or the delete button I need to ignore the input. But any normal printable symbol I want to catch. I get the input in the text field() method of a QKeyEvent.

I've tried two regexps

The first one was:

```
QRegExp("[\\S]");
```

Which did not work as apparently pressing delete is considered a non-whitespace character.

The second one was

```
QRegExp("[\\w]");
```

This one was much better as it would only accept letters, number and underscore but no symbols such as + or *. Which I want to accept.

I was thinking of modifying the last expression to include any symbol in my keyboard. But how would I do that? Or how can I write an RegExp for what I want?

Comment: What about a negative character class (with a leading ^ that matches everything except the things listed)

Comment: Well, I really feel you want to use `QRegExp(".");`

Comment: If I use the . doesn't that mean anything? Including any "unicode char"?

Comment: Well this is what I did. As long as anyone doesn't see anything wrong with it, I'm sticking to it: acceptedInput = QRegExp("[\\w\\+\\-\\.~!@#$%\\^&\\*\\(\\);:\\\\\\/\\|\\<\\>\\\"\\'?,\\{\\}\\[\\]]");

Comment: Surely, it matches everything. Can't you enter a Unicode char from your keyboard?

Comment: The problem is that if it matches anything, won't it match also whatever he code is for a delete or a home?

Comment: Are you sure you want to check the **text** carried by the event, and not merely which key button was pressed? And are you sure you don't simply want to install shortcuts?

Comment: Why are you using `QRegExp` and not checking the character class using `QChar`?

Comment: I'm not checking character class, because until you mentioned I did no know about it. I'll look into it. @peppe, maybe there Is something I'm missing but I said I'm doing just that. Checking the text carried by the event. And no. I don't want any shortcuts.